# On migrating to SplashScreen API 12 with Single Activity Architecture

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-splashscreen

We are considering implementing our SplashScreen using Splash Screen API, but since we use a Single Activity Architecture, we use a fragment to present the splash screen instead of a separate Activity. Is having this MainActivity implement the API discouraged/risky? Is there a best practice to adapting this single activity to handle that other responsibility? Or is it necessary to create a separate activity to handle this?

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

please check https://proandroiddev.com/splashscreen-api-android-12-part-1-b2272e0ae98e

Hope this helps, Answering your question, Yes shouldn't be any problem as android helps us to create splash activity.